# My computer turns on, however, it makes a huge drill noise. What can I do?

Tags: laptop, memory, desktop

Yesterday, (as of writing this), I was upgrading my desktop's components, (the hard drive and RAM), using the components from my laptops, to make a long story short, they didn't work, but I couldn't put in the RAM, so I woke up (today, as of writing this) at 5:30 AM to fix the RAM issue, managed to put it in, and now my computer boots, however, a noise that sounded like a drill started, I instantly turned off my PC, then, when I turned it back on, it just did nothing (nothing I could see was on the monitor because it was unplugged at the time). I assume it may have been due to the RAM. Help me out.

Edit: I ordered a new computer, so I can safely say that this question may be ignored.
My PC is a HP Compaq, (don't know what model it is, but it is from 2010).

Comment: RAM does not make any noise. You have managed to destroy something else. You now need a repair-shop.

Comment: Such sound generally come from fan. If it is dirty or if something is touching it. Probably a loose wire. HDD make some noise too but that is very low.

Comment: Based on your description, I would say a cable is hitting a fan. Given that the pc is not turning on anymore, its most likely a cable hitting the CPU fan.

Answer (score 2):

The description of the sound is most likely a cable (usually one from the power supply to cd-rom drive, or harddrive, that is hitting a fan (most likely the CPU fan).

I've had this happen my accident too and it sounded like a drill, so I can relate.